# I want to apply table rates shipping based on price AFTER DISCOUNT in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount, tax-calculation

I want to apply table rates shipping based on price AFTER DISCOUNT in Magento 2.

For Ex. Here(https://prnt.sc/o4albv) is shipping apply on Subtotal amount $2676.

I want to Shipping apply on (Subtotal)-(Discount) = remaining amount

Ex. $2676 - $1070.40 = $1605.60

Comment: did you find any solution?